# Slide menu as facebook app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios4, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have found a code that slide de view and put a ViewController but I don't wanna put a ViewController, the view which I need to add to slide menu is in the same viewcontroller. I need only add this UIView in underleft slide.

OBS.: I'm not using storyboard on this project. I need add an UIView in slidingView

Here is the code thats add the a ViewController:

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  // shadowPath, shadowOffset, and rotation is handled by ECSlidingViewController.
  // You just need to set the opacity, radius, and color.
  self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
  self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
  self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

  if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
  }

  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `ECSlidingViewController`...

`underLeftViewController` is a property and refers to a view controller.

You have to create a new class that inherits from UIViewController and instantiate it. Then you will assign it to `underLeftViewController`

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = vc;
```

Other way, if you don't want to create a new class you can declare a basic view controller and assign it to `underLeftViewController`

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init]
//settings for vc
self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = vc;
```